# Авторизация через google. Ошибка установки аватара аккаунта

Tags: android, firebase

Реализую в приложении авторизацию через гугл, используя firebase. Авторизация проходит успешно, если у пользователя установлен свой аватар в профиле, в противном случае вылетает ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: avocado.droid.lexicon, PID: 11403
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{avocado.droid.lexicon/avocado.droid.lexicon.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3303)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3411)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1994)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.net.Uri.toString()' on a null object reference
    at avocado.droid.lexicon.fragment.AccountFragment.handleSignInResult(AccountFragment.java:115)
    at avocado.droid.lexicon.fragment.AccountFragment.onStart(AccountFragment.java:172)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:2477)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1494)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3235)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:212)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:628)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1339)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7403)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
```

AccountFragment

```
    public class AccountFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 007;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    private SignInButton btnSignIn;
    private Button btnSignOut, btnRevokeAccess;
    private LinearLayout llProfileLayout;
    private ImageView imgProfilePic;
    private TextView txtName, txtEmail;

    public AccountFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_account, container, false);
        btnSignIn = (SignInButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
        btnSignOut = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_out);
        btnRevokeAccess = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_revoke_access);
        llProfileLayout = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.llProfile);
        imgProfilePic = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgProfilePic);
        txtName = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
        txtEmail = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtEmail);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnSignOut.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRevokeAccess.setOnClickListener(this);

        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .enableAutoManage(getActivity(), this)
                .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                .build();

        btnSignIn.setSize(SignInButton.SIZE_STANDARD);
        btnSignIn.setScopes(gso.getScopeArray());

        return rootView;
    }

    private void signIn() {
        Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient);
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
    }


    private void signOut() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void revokeAccess() {
        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(mGoogleApiClient).setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResult(Status status) {
                        updateUI(false);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
            String personName = acct.getDisplayName();
            String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            String email = acct.getEmail();

            txtName.setText(personName);
            txtEmail.setText(email);
            Glide.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imgProfilePic);

            updateUI(true);
        } else {

            updateUI(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int id = v.getId();

        switch (id) {
            case R.id.btn_sign_in:
                signIn();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_sign_out:
                signOut();
                break;

            case R.id.btn_revoke_access:
                revokeAccess();
                break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
            handleSignInResult(result);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (opr.isDone()) {

         GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
            handleSignInResult(result);
        } else {
            showProgressDialog();
            opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                    hideProgressDialog();
                    handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Как сделать рабочую авторизацию, ведь не у всех пользователей установлен аватар? И почему не отображается в аватаре первая буква имени, если он не установлен, как в других приложениях?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В папку drawable кладем картинку, которая будет загружена, если у пользователя в гугл аккаунте не установлен аватар. И оборачиваем код в try-catch

```
 try {
           String personPhotoUrl = acct.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            Glide.with(getActivity().getApplicationContext()).load(personPhotoUrl)
                    .thumbnail(0.5f)
                    .crossFade()
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                    .into(imgProfilePic);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            imgProfilePic.setImageResource(R.drawable.default_user_avatar);
        }

        updateUI(true);
```